# Error with PDO (Prepared Statement) - Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I've decided to migrate my project to prepared statements, and I am with an error after executing the following code:

```
$sql = 'SELECT clanID FROM clan_users WHERE userID = :uid LIMIT 1';
$data = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
$data->execute(array(':uid' => $uid));
$data->fetchAll();

return $data['0']['clanid'];
```

Error returned:

```
 Fatal error: Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array in
/var/www/game/classes/Clan.class on line 689
```

var_dump($data) returns:

```
object(PDOStatement)[122]
    public 'queryString' => string 'SELECT clanID FROM clan_users WHERE userID = :uid LIMIT 1' (length=57)
```

The value of $uid is correct, and selecting manually at mysql returns the expected row. I also tried changing to

```
$data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

but didnt work too.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `$data` variable is just the statement.  You actually need the result of the `$data->fetchAll()` to be populated into a different variable like this

```
$data_array = $data->fetchAll();
```

You then work with $data_array, not with `$data` directly.